# Split array into half with equal or approximately equal array sum

Tags: php, arrays

Problem:

Array with numeric values needs to be split in half with approximately equal or if possible equal array sum. Number or order of elements in arrays is not important.

```
$probabilites = array(0.4, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3); # 1.45

$probabilites[0] = array(0.4, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1); # 0.75
$probabilites[1] = array(0.2, 0.2, 0.3); # 0.7
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Should the given order be maintained? Is e.g. `array(0.4, 0.15, 0.2)` and `array(0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3)` valid? (If yes, I guess this will complicate matters.)

Comment: @jensgram, I wrote that it is not important at all, only sum of both arrays should be as close as possible. Yes, it is valid, we can't split 7 elements into half, 4 + 3 would be ideal. MarvinLabs, ~= :) You can see in example, 0.75 is close to 0.7 and vice versa.

Comment: My first attempt had a big O of YECK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
<?php
$in = array(0.4, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3);

// Sort array decreasing
rsort($in, SORT_NUMERIC);

// Start with two empty arrays
$arr1 = $arr2 = array();

// Put the next value in the array in the array with the lowest sum
foreach ($in as $value)
  if (array_sum($arr2) > array_sum($arr1)) $arr1[] = $value; else $arr2[] = $value;

// Wrap in array (as in question)
$out = array($arr1,$arr2);
```

Comment: Waiting 30s to accept correct answer. Very clever I must say :)

Comment: This won't work right if the values are very different from each other (although it will be ok if they are close). This is the very famous Knapsack problem BTW.

Comment: I've tested it couple of times and it works as expected.. http://pokit.etf.ba/get/500b563910d333cd07739b48a4256c38.png

Comment: One example is (10, 0, -100).

Comment: Ah! +1, good catch, no negative values! But that is not what the Knapsack problem is about :) @TS, did you need negative values as well? Otherwise, use `if ((array_sum($arr2) > array_sum($arr1)) xor $value < 0)` as condition.

Comment: My bad for not pointing out, values are positive, with total array sum of 1 (weights).

Comment: Although now a solution for also negative numbers would be interesting. Would it work if you sorted the array descending by abs(n) and than append the value to the smallest or highest sum depending on its signum?

Comment: +1 Optim: instead of array_sum each time, you can easily cache the sum of the arrays $arr1 and $arr2. Will save time.

Comment: @pelle-ten-cate 100,50,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15 doesn't work optimally. You should be able to put 150 in each box, but this algorithm gives 145 in one and 155 in the other. This is the Knapsack problem, and there is a reason it's NP-Complete. (Take the sum of all the numbers, then divide by two - that's the size of the knapsack.)

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware that this is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem ?

And it's NP-Complete, so you can't do it fast.

For a small list it won't be too bad, if you have a larger list see some of the solutions on the wikipedia page.

Comment: Thank you for the link, that is basically it, array will have no more then couple of dozen values with array sum of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Start with an empty array A and the given array B (in your example $probabilities):

- Remove first elements of B and append it to A.
- Calculate both array sums and calculate the difference.
- Repeat this until the difference gets worse.
- When the difference gets worse (i.e. larger) reverse the last step and you are done.

Or to save time:

- First calculate the sum of B = sum0.
- Remove first elements of B and append it to A.
- Compare sum (a) with sum0/2.
- Repeat until it gets worse and reverse the last step.

Comment: No, this won't always work. Imagine the values being 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 10, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1. The best would be to have the 10 in one array, and all six 0.1 entries in the other. Your algorithm will have you ended up with 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 in array one, and 10, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 in array two.

Comment: As OP maintained the order of the original array, I followed his example.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I did tried something similar, but I was sure there is other way, Pelle ten Cate provided very nice solution. I am sorry about order, that was just coincidence. Thank you again.

Comment: Well, I guess, if it was only for the example, I would just do it manually. Giving the TS the credit for agreeing on that with me, I thought other lists of numbers would come as well. :)

Comment: Yeah, your approach surely is more sophisticated and yields a better splitting than mine. Unless you get an array like (2, 3, -5). Which would yield (2, -5) and (3). But my approach would also fail epicly on that input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sort an array, start from biggest values. Put another values to one of 2 array where sum is smaller. Anyone can check this solution ?